# JQuery load help

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use load() to place some html into a div on a page. I have a bunch of links  like this:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slides">
        <div class="projects">
            <a href="work/mobus.html" title="Mobus Fabrics Website">
                <img src="images/work/mobus.jpg" alt="Mobus Fabrics Website" width="280" height="100" />
            </a>

            <a href="work/eglin.html" title="Eglin Ltd Website">
                <img src="images/work/eglin.jpg" alt="Eglin Ltd Website" width="280" height="100" />
            </a>

            <a href="work/first-brands.html" title="First Brands Website">
                <img src="images/work/first-brands.jpg" alt="First Brands Website" width="280" height="100" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <a id="prev"></a>
        <a id="next"></a>
    </div>
```

and my jquery code looks like this:

```
$('.projects a').click(function() {
    $('#work').load(this.href);
});
```

The problem is when clicked the html is placed in the #work div the html is loaded in another page. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "The problem is when clicked the html is placed in the #work div the html is loaded in another page." Also I don't see any elements in your html with an ID of work. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Also, if you pages (ex.: work/mobus.html) are full pages and contains <html></html> tags, you'll end up with an invalid DOM

Comment: @JohnFx The problem was I had another ID with the same name. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action to stop the href being loaded:

```
$('.projects a').click(function(event) {
    $('#work').load(this.href);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You may also see people achieving the same by doing:

```
$('.projects a').click(function(event) {
    $('#work').load(this.href);

    return false;
});
```

However, this method will stop the event bubbling any further, as well as preventing the default action. If you've got any `delegate` or `live` methods listening for the same event further up the DOM tree, doing `return false` will stop these handlers being called.

Edit: For the callback function:

```
$('.projects a').click(function(event) {
    $('#work').load(this.href, function (text) {
        alert("This loaded: " + text);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Matt that seems to disable the whole button it doesn't load the href but it also doesn't place the html in #work

Comment: It will do. Check that there is an element with an id of work. Try adding a callback function to ensure the request is completing: add a function as a second parameter and add a simple alert or something. See my edit for an example. Add an alert inside the click event to prove the handler is being called.

Comment: @Matt I had another id on the page with the same name. Thanks a lot for the help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the event from chaining.. the browser will eventually follow the link.

See preventDefault